# R- Trimming a string in a dataframe after a particular pattern

Tags: r, regex, dataframe, trim

I am having trouble figuring out how to trim the end off of a string in a data frame.

I want to trim everything to a "base" name, after #s and letters, a period, then a number. My goal is trim everything in my dataframe to this "base" name, then sum the values with the same "base." I was thinking it would be possible to trim, then merge and sum the values.

```
    ie/
    Gene_name   Values
    B0222.5     4
    B0222.6     16
    B0228.7.1   2
    B0228.7.2   12
    B0350.2h.1  30
    B0350.2h.2  2
    B0350.2i    15
    2RSSE.1a    3
    2RSSE.1b    10
    R02F11.11   4
```

to

```
    Gene_name   Values
    B0222.5     4
    B0222.6     16
    B0228.7     14
    B0350.2     47
    2RSSE.1     13
    R02F11.11   4
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Catch your "base" names using this regex `([[:alnum:]]+\.[[:digit:]]+)` (or `([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[0-9]+)` - both are equivalent) and then reduce your array based on the matches. Regex cannot *easily* perform calculations (it's not really feasible and more of a hack if you do manage to get it working)

Comment: Might be easiest to create a new array with the regex matches (default to value of 0) then add to that array key based on each successive match using a loop. I'm not familiar with R but that's how I'd make this work in most other languages. `a= [[B0222.5, 4], ..., [B0228.7.1, 2], [B0228.7.2, 12], ...]` => loop each key/value pair => first match = `B0222.5` => `b=[[B0222.5, 4]]` => ... => third match = `B0228.7` => b = `[[B0222.5, 4], ..., [B0228.7, 2]]` => fourth match =`B0228.7` => b = `[[B0222.5, 4], ..., [B0228.7, 14]]` etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution using the `dplyr` and `stringr` packages. You first create a column with your extracted base pattern, and then use the `group_by` and `summarise` functions from `dplyr` to get the sum of values for each name:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df2 = df %>% mutate(Gene_name = str_extract(Gene_name,"[[:alnum:]]+\\.\\d+")) %>% 
group_by(Gene_name) %>% summarise(Values = sum(Values))

  Gene_name Values
      <chr>  <int>
1   2RSSE.1     13
2   B0222.5      4
3   B0222.6     16
4   B0228.7     14
5   B0350.2     47
6 R02F11.11      4
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone has also suggested, I would get gene names first, and then search for them in the original data.frame

```
df <- data.frame(Gene_name = c("B0222.5", "B0222.6", "B0228.7.1",  "B0228.7.2", "B0350.2h.1", "B0350.2h.2", "B0350.2i", "2RSSE.1a", "2RSSE.1b", "R02F11.11"),
                 Values = c(4, 16, 2, 12, 30, 2, 15, 3, 10, 4),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

pat <- "(^[[:alnum:]]+\\.[[:digit:]]*)"
cap.pos <- regexpr(pat,  df$Gene_name)
cap.gene <- unique(substr(df$Gene_name, cap.pos, (cap.pos + attributes(cap.pos)$match.length - 1)))

do.call(rbind, lapply(cap.gene, (function(nm){
  sumval <- sum(df[grepl(nm, df$Gene_name, fixed = T),]$Values, na.rm = T)
  data.frame(Gene_name = nm, Value = sumval)
})))
```

The result tracks with your request

```
  Gene_name Value
1   B0222.5     4
2   B0222.6    16
3   B0228.7    14
4   B0350.2    47
5   2RSSE.1    13
6 R02F11.11     4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create the Gene_name as a factor and change the levels.

```
# coerce the vector as a factor
Gene_name <- as.factor(Gene_name)
# view the levels
levels(Gene_name)
# to make B0228.7.1 into B0228.7
levels(Gene_name)[ *index for B0228.7.1* ] <- B0228.7
```

You can repeat this for the levels that need to change and then the values will automatically sum together and rows with similar levels will be treated as the same category.